# How do I force Perforce to add files to changelist?

Tags: perforce

I'm a very fresh user of Perfoce, so please be patient!

I am trying to create a commit (I understand it that in Perforce it is called a changelist) of the files which have been changed. It sort of happens automatically in other VC systems, but there seems to be no easy way of doing it in `p4`... The problem is (maybe) that I'm not editing the files by hand, the files are generated (please don't ask me why do I have to check in the generated files...) so the whole directory tree is getting removed and then copied over with the new files. But Perforce acts as if nothing happened. In both my workspace and the depot it displays the updated files, but when someone will check them out on another machine, the files will be of the previous version.

I'm fine with doing it either through GUI or through the command line. I'd prefer the command line, because that would spare me the trouble in the long run, but it doesn't seem like it should be much hassle either way.

In other words, let's say, this is the workflow I'm used to from SVN or Git:

- Run `status` to see what changed.
- Stage / add to commit what you want to be in the next revision.
- Commit and send it to the versioning server.

What I'm not able to do is the "stage" phase - because the changes are not discovered automatically.

**EDIT**
Ah, I think, I figured it out: reconciliation was what I needed... well, I guess if you don't marry, this word would hardly ever happen in your vocabulary :)

Comment: Yes, 'p4 reconcile' is the best tool for doing the 'stage' operation. There is also 'p4 status' if you prefer that command: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/status.html#1048796

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the proper command is `reconcile`. Also, as Bryan Pendleton suggested there should be `status`, but I must have an older version of Perforces, which doesn't have this command. This command is also available from context menu in either depot or workspace panels of Perforce graphical interface, when you click on the modified file.

Comment: "p4 status" shows you what "p4 reconcile" would do, without doing it. That's all.